# How to allow theme update downloads to WordPress installs only?

Tags: updates

I am working on custom theme update script that works fine but after the update if you click on update success notification link  "Show Details" , the full link to update is displayed.

[image]

and since I was doing this in my download script

```
if(isset($_GET['download'])){

    // run download

}else{

    exit;

}
```

you were able to copy the link and download the zip directly.

I checked another download script that checks for user_agent , and if WordPress string is within it allows the download  so I made a mod to my script like so

```
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if(isset($_GET['download']) && stristr( $user_agent, 'WordPress' ) == TRUE ){

    // run download

}else{

    exit;

}
```

now I am not sure how reliable this is so my question is is there a reliable string/header anything that is sent by update-core.php?action=do-theme-upgrade

that I can check for to make sure that only WordPress install is allowed to download the update.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` is something you should not rely on.

This can be anything from:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
```

to

```
☆*:｡゜ﾟ･*ヽ(^ᴗ^)ﾉ*･゜ﾟ｡:*☆ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯(ಠ益ಠ)(ಥ‿ಥ)(ʘ‿ʘ)ლ(ಠ_ಠლ)( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)ヽ(ﾟДﾟ)ﾉʕ•̫͡•ʔᶘ ᵒᴥᵒᶅ(=^ ^=)oO
```

So you need to thinker something other to rely upon.

---

Why don't you simply use form action `do-theme-upgrade`?

```
File: wp-admin/update-core.php
336: function list_theme_updates() {
337:    $themes = get_theme_updates();
338:    if ( empty( $themes ) ) {
339:        echo '<h2>' . __( 'Themes' ) . '</h2>';
340:        echo '<p>' . __( 'Your themes are all up to date.' ) . '</p>';
341:        return;
342:    }
343: 
344:    $form_action = 'update-core.php?action=do-theme-upgrade';
```

Comment: not sure how I would use it,  I need something sent to my script to trigger the download

Comment: The link you click will send the form, why don't you find some hooks inside `update-core.php` where you will add your custom logic?

Comment: that is what I am looking for , but cant find the ref, will look more , thnx

Comment: No problem@Benn, if you really get in trouble we will take a look.